# Produce a sentence from a grammar with a given number of terminals

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, parsing, nlp, grammar

Say you've got a toy grammar, like: *(updated so the output looks more natural)*

```
S -> ${NP} ${VP} | ${S} and ${S} | ${S}, after which ${S}

NP -> the ${N} | the ${A} ${N} | the ${A} ${A} ${N}

VP -> ${V} ${NP}

N -> dog | fish | bird | wizard

V -> kicks | meets | marries

A -> red | striped | spotted
```

e.g., "the dog kicks the red wizard", "the bird meets the spotted fish or the wizard marries the striped dog"

How can you produce a sentence from this grammar according to the constraint that it must contain a total of *n* Vs + As + Ns. Given an integer the sentence must contain that many terminals. (note of course in this grammar the minimum possible *n* is 3).

Comment: Is there a specific random distribution that you're trying to achieve over all sentences with n terminals?

Comment: The minimum is 5, and you can't do 10 or 11.

Comment: The sentences can be pretty strange. "either either the dog kicks the bird or the dog kicks the bird or the dog kicks the bird". Do you want to restrict the grammar to be more like English?

Comment: @ucleo#1: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think the minimum is N + V + N, 3. I don't care about the 'the' determiner, I'm counting that as part of the NP non-terminal (perhaps I've used the term incorrectly).

Comment: I agree minimum is 3, but given rules for S I don't see a maximum?  Unless terminal duplication is prohibited?

Comment: The minimum word count is 5. The minimum value for n is 3, where there will be two Ns and one V; "the" is neither N nor V nor A.

Comment: @uncleo#2: you're right, nesting the S's more than once looks weird, but that's why context-free grammars aren't always a great representation of human language. I was trying and perhaps not doing the best job to make something that would be able to produce sentences of arbitrary length. I would be open to suggestion on making it better.

Comment: Cut the word "either" and you're on your way....

Comment: yea I changed it so it doesn't look quite so weird.

Comment: We had an assignment similar to this when I was in college.  One of the test inputs was specifically made to address the non randomness of the rand() function on the system we were running.  The rand() implementation alternated between even and odd, and if you just did a rand()%X the test grammar was constructed to generate an infinite loop.  The solution was to use a different random number generator or use the high order bits of the rand function (which are more random according to the man page e.g. (rand()>>4) %X).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Python code will generate a random sentence with the given number of terminals.
It works by counting the number of ways to produce a sentence of a given length, generating a large random number, and computing the indicated sentence.
The count is done recursively, with memoization.
An empty right hand side produces 1 sentence if n is 0 and 0 sentences otherwise.
To count the number of sentences produced by a nonempty right hand side, sum over i, the number of terminals used by the first symbol in the right hand side.
For each i, multiply the number of possibilities for the rest of the right hand side by the number of possibilities for the first symbol.
If the first symbol is a terminal, there is 1 possibility if i is 1 and 0 otherwise.
If the first symbol is a nonterminal, sum the possibilities over each alternative.
To avoid infinite loops, we have to be careful to prune the recursive calls when a quantity is 0.
This may still loop infinitely if the grammar has infinitely many derivations of one sentence.
For example, in the grammar

```
S -> S S
S ->
```

there are infinitely many derivations of the empty sentence: S => , S => S S => , S => S S => S S S => , etc.
The code to find a particular sentence is a straightforward modification of the code to count them.
This code is reasonably efficient, generating 100 sentences with 100 terminals each in less than a second.

```
import collections
import random

class Grammar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prods = collections.defaultdict(list)
        self.numsent = {}
        self.weight = {}

    def prod(self, lhs, *rhs):
        self.prods[lhs].append(rhs)
        self.numsent.clear()

    def countsent(self, rhs, n):
        if n < 0:
            return 0
        elif not rhs:
            return 1 if n == 0 else 0
        args = (rhs, n)
        if args not in self.numsent:
            sym = rhs[0]
            rest = rhs[1:]
            total = 0
            if sym in self.prods:
                for i in xrange(1, n + 1):
                    numrest = self.countsent(rest, n - i)
                    if numrest > 0:
                        for rhs1 in self.prods[sym]:
                            total += self.countsent(rhs1, i) * numrest
            else:
                total += self.countsent(rest, n - self.weight.get(sym, 1))
            self.numsent[args] = total
        return self.numsent[args]

    def getsent(self, rhs, n, j):
        assert 0 <= j < self.countsent(rhs, n)
        if not rhs:
            return ()
        sym = rhs[0]
        rest = rhs[1:]
        if sym in self.prods:
            for i in xrange(1, n + 1):
                numrest = self.countsent(rest, n - i)
                if numrest > 0:
                    for rhs1 in self.prods[sym]:
                        dj = self.countsent(rhs1, i) * numrest
                        if dj > j:
                            j1, j2 = divmod(j, numrest)
                            return self.getsent(rhs1, i, j1) + self.getsent(rest, n - i, j2)
                        j -= dj
            assert False
        else:
            return (sym,) + self.getsent(rest, n - self.weight.get(sym, 1), j)

    def randsent(self, sym, n):
        return self.getsent((sym,), n, random.randrange(self.countsent((sym,), n)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = Grammar()
    g.prod('S', 'NP', 'VP')
    g.prod('S', 'S', 'and', 'S')
    g.prod('S', 'S', 'after', 'which', 'S')
    g.prod('NP', 'the', 'N')
    g.prod('NP', 'the', 'A', 'N')
    g.prod('NP', 'the', 'A', 'A', 'N')
    g.prod('VP', 'V', 'NP')
    g.prod('N', 'dog')
    g.prod('N', 'fish')
    g.prod('N', 'bird')
    g.prod('N', 'wizard')
    g.prod('V', 'kicks')
    g.prod('V', 'meets')
    g.prod('V', 'marries')
    g.prod('A', 'red')
    g.prod('A', 'striped')
    g.prod('A', 'spotted')
    g.weight.update({'and': 0, 'after': 0, 'which': 0, 'the': 0})
    for i in xrange(100):
        print ' '.join(g.randsent('S', 3))
```

Comment: If it's an "empty range" error, it means that there aren't any sentences of that length.

Comment: Ah, I see... this is close but not quite right, though. It looks like it's going on the total number of words output, rather than the terminals, the N's, V's and A's only. 'the' and 'and' are part of non-terminals and shouldn't count, in other words.

Comment: I updated the code to allow weights to be specified. For simplicity, I made the assumption that no nonterminal is nullable.

Comment: Hmm, I've seen the terms 'rhs' and 'lhs' before.... here: http://tinyurl.com/l75l48 . Can I ask you where I can learn more about this stuff? I'm still learning this stuff and it's not something I necessarily always find intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the best solution, but I'd recursively work my way through each rule of the grammar until I've exceeded the constraint, then pop back and explore another path along the grammar.  Keep all the sentences that meet the constraint and throw out all the sentences that don't.

For example, with n = 3:

S -> (${NP} ${VP}) -> ( (the ${N}) ${VP}) -> ( (the (dog) ${VP}) -> ... -> ( (the (dog) ( (kicks) (the ${NP} ) ) ) ) -> ( (the (dog) ( (kicks) (the (dog) ) ) ) )

And then pop back

( (the (dog) ( (kicks) (the ${N} ) ) ) ) -> ( (the (dog) ( (kicks) (the (fish) ) ) ) )

and a little while later...

( (the (dog) ( ${V} ${N} ) ) ) -> ( (the (dog) ( (meets) ${N} ) ) ) -> ( (the (dog) ( (meets) the (dog) ) ) )

etc.

Essentially a depth-first graph search, only you are building the graph as you are searching it (and you stop building parts that exceed the constraints).

Answer (score 0):

This question contains a category error.  The grammar you've specified has the appearance of a context free grammar, but the requirement that there be a specific number of terminal nodes requires a recursively enumerable grammar.

Comment: you may be right but I can only find a handful of hits on google for "recursively enumerable grammar" that aren't obscure conference papers